# Unable to apply display settings for external monitor on Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, external-monitor

I am trying to set up an external monitor as an extended display for my laptop. [Ryzen 4800H + GTX1650]

When booting up, the monitor briefly shows the boot screen for a second but then switches to the “no signal” message.

Even though the settings detects the external monitor, nothing pops up on it when I am trying to change the display settings. When I click on “joint display” or “mirror” and hit “apply” to save the changes in settings, it just resets to single screen. No change observed whatsoever.

I have checked for connection issues. That is not the problem. Also, works flawlessly with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this commandes :

`sudo xrandr -q` : to show all external port for display and resolution screen

`sudo xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1360x768` : to set configuration for second display

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the response! I tried this to add an sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 1920x1080 and got a BadMatch error.

Comment: What is the output for sudo xrandr -q??

Comment: Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
eDP connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  39.98  
   
HDMI-1-0 connected primary
   1920x1080     60.00 +  74.97    59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    70.00    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
  Removed some lower resolutions for character limit.

Comment: you have to type this command: `sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-1-0 1920x1080`

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems (Ubuntu 20.10 Gnome), and solve this problem by installing a proprietary nvidia driver and in "NVIDIA X Server Settings" switch "PRIME Profile" to "Performance mode". After reboot external monitor earned.

Comment: Could you please **edit** your answer and also add the commands / steps you implemented when installing those drivers (including their names)? This would really help future users stumbling upon this answer.